# Django most efficient way to count users and types

Tags: django

In my django project I have a user model and I want to count the different status of users. I am not sure the best way to approach as thats the top most level model so i dont think I can use annotate.

I tried it but of course i on

```
workers = get_user_model().objects.annotate(
            not_active_workers=Count("id", filter=Q(is_active=False, status=0))
        ).annotate(
            active_not_complete_workers=Count("id", filter=Q(is_active=True, profile_completed=False, status=0))
        ).annotate(
            complete_applicant_workers=Count("id", filter=Q(is_active=True, profile_completed=True, status=0))
        ).annotate(
            former_workers=Count("id", filter=Q(is_active=False, status=2))
        ).annotate(
            accepted_workers=Count("id", filter=Q(is_active=False, status=1))
        ).filter(role=2)

dict(
  not_active=workers[0].not_active_workers,
  active_not_complete=workers[0].active_not_complete_workers,
  complete_applicant=workers[0].complete_applicant_workers,
  former=workers[0].former_workers,
  accepted=workers[0].accepted_workers, 
)
```

The other way is count() for each filter, but it would be several queries. I think these would be pretty fast but maybe Im missing an easier way to count all queries as a dataset in 1 hit?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't an easier way to do this because your filters are complex and exist as `Q()` objects within the `Count` filter. Aggregate is not appropriate here and the other method of using `.values()` wouldn't work - example:

```py
User.objects.values('type').order_by('type').annotate(user_count=Count('type'))
# Output: [{'type': 'user', 'user_count': 3}, {'type': 'admin', 'user_count': 1}, ...
```

The only improvement I can suggest is a reformat:

```py
workers = get_user_model().objects.annotate(
        not_active_workers=Count("id", filter=Q(is_active=False, status=0)),
        active_not_complete_workers=Count("id", filter=Q(is_active=True, profile_completed=False, status=0)),
        complete_applicant_workers=Count("id", filter=Q(is_active=True, profile_completed=True, status=0)),
        former_workers=Count("id", filter=Q(is_active=False, status=2)),
        accepted_workers=Count("id", filter=Q(is_active=False, status=1))
    ).filter(role=2)
```

You could also add `.first()` and remove all of your `[0]` notation in the following dict but that's splitting hairs!